# PHP Update multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP/HTML Code that is selecting data from a MySQL Database:

```
<?php
    $sql3="SELECT * from property_images where property_seq = '".$property["sequence"]."' ";
    $rs3=mysql_query($sql3,$conn);
    while($property_img=mysql_fetch_array($rs3))
    {
        ?><tr>
          <td colspan="2"><img src="http://domain.co.uk/img/property-images/<?php echo $property_img["image"]; ?>" width="80px" height="80px" /></td>
          <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" name="image1" value="Y" <?php if($property_img["image1"] == 'Y') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
          <input type="checkbox" name="image2" value="Y" <?php if($property_img["image2"] == 'Y') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
          <input type="checkbox" name="image3" value="Y" <?php if($property_img["image3"] == 'Y') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
          <input type="checkbox" name="image4" value="Y" <?php if($property_img["image4"] == 'Y') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
          <input type="checkbox" name="image5" value="Y" <?php if($property_img["image5"] == 'Y') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
          <input type="checkbox" name="image6" value="Y" <?php if($property_img["image6"] == 'Y') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
          <input type="checkbox" name="image7" value="Y" <?php if($property_img["image7"] == 'Y') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
          <input type="checkbox" name="image8" value="Y" <?php if($property_img["image8"] == 'Y') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
          <input type="checkbox" name="image9" value="Y" <?php if($property_img["image9"] == 'Y') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
          <input type="checkbox" name="image10" value="Y" <?php if($property_img["image10"] == 'Y') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
          <input type="checkbox" name="image11" value="Y" <?php if($property_img["image11"] == 'Y') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
          <input type="checkbox" name="image12" value="Y" <?php if($property_img["image12"] == 'Y') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
          <input type="checkbox" name="image13" value="Y" <?php if($property_img["image13"] == 'Y') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> /></td>
        </tr><?php
    }
    ?>
```

each row, has its own image with the columns *image1 - image13*

i want to update the table with the checkboxes that are checked and unchecked on the form update

how is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear my friend

Comment: Ok - i will update. hold on...

Comment: does it make sense now?

Comment: Ill post an answer soon. I think Bibear answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to update the $property_img["imagexx"] val on db depending on the user click on the checkbox you must use ajax.

Fire an event on triggering each checkbox and send the value to a php page that update the php.

Jquery Ajax function can help you on this task.

L

Comment: would it be easier to use a for loop in php?

Comment: It more or less the same. For me the Ajax approach is lighter since it use only those items that have been modified and not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

name all your checkboxes images[]

```
<input type="checkbox" name="images[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="images[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="images[]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="images[]" value="4" />
```

You can then update with PHP :

```
<?php
$q = "UPDATE property_images SET";
foreach($_POST["images"] as $image) {
     $q .= "  image" . $image ." = 'Y', ";
}
$q .= " property_seq = '".$property["sequence"]."' WHERE property_seq = '".$property["sequence"]."'";
mysql_query($q);
?>
```

Comment: 13 queries just to update 1 row? that sounds nasty xD

Comment: works great, but its updating ALL rows with the same for example. update property_images set image1 = 'Y' where property_seq = '1' - there are multiple rows with the same property_seq, sequence is the unique column. how can i do this?

Comment: You are updating all rows on table at the same time, also, you are not setting imagex='N' on the unchecked ones!

Comment: i dont need to set imageX = 'N' at all. it can just be blank. how can i make it update where sequence = '1' and not property_seq = '1'

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, mysql_ functions are deprecated, please google mysqli_ or PDO, mysql_ won't be supported on future versions, and is unsafe, etc**

Your html output could be much simpler with a loop, also have an eye on putting the sequence number on a hidden field or something first:

```
<?php
    $sql3="SELECT * from property_images where property_seq = '".$property["sequence"]."' ";
    $rs3=mysql_query($sql3,$conn);
    while($property_img=mysql_fetch_array($rs3)){
?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><img src="http://domain.co.uk/img/property-images/<?php echo $property_img["image"]; ?>" width="80px" height="80px" /></td>

            <!-- THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT: send the sequence or ID through a hidden field, to know which row you are gonna update later-->
            <input type="hidden" name="sequence" value="<?php echo $property_img['sequence']; ?>"/>

            <td colspan="2">
                <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 13; $i++): ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="images[]>" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php if($property_img["image$i"] == 'Y') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
                <?php endfor ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

---

Then this is the next page where the update is done, have a good look at the comments:

```
<?php
    //Handle as you want the situation when there are no images selected instead of using an exit(), I used it here just for the quickness;
    if(count($_POST['images'] < 1) exit('no images where selected to update');

    $images = array();
    for($i = 1; $i <= 13; $i++){
        $string = "image$i = ";
        if(in_array($i, $_POST['images'])){
            $string .= "'Y'"; //notice the double quoting here, it's important
        } else {
            //This updates the table so if it was checked when loaded, but unchecked by the user, this makes the change!
            $string .= "'N'";
        }
    }

    //This creates a string like: image1 = 'Y', images2 = 'N', etc...
    $images = implode(', ', $images );

    //try to sanitize the query first ... I won't cos am just showing you your question xD
    $sql = "UPDATE property_images SET $images WHERE property_seq = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[sequence]) . ";
    mysql_query($sql,$conn);
?>
```

Comment: Yikes. It's great that you're advocating the use of PDO, but in your code here you have `$_POST` data put directly in a query. That's radioactively bad code.

Comment: I was at work, and rushing that piece of code, If you read the commented line before that line, you will see that I'm telling him to sanitize the values of the query first xD. You people never read 100% of the things :P. I was guiding him, don´t need to do everything perfect, also I didn´t sanitize and validate there because it´s in plain mysql, it´s pain in the ass to do it, that´s one of the reasons I´m recommending PDO, I would have used prepared statements XD

Comment: Some people use the same excuses at work, then later when their site is completely cracked open they realize the mistake they've made. Just saying this is extremely dangerous without `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Again, I told to sanitize the query in the comments, if you can't read is not my fault, I wasn't going to do all the small details about security here because it wasn't the point at all, just warning him about it was more than enough, If not I would just had told him to switch to PDO and not trying to help with the code. The user is just learning the very basics, let him learn step by step. And thanks about concerning about my work, the 100% of the queries are PDO prepared statements, I'm using MVC so every query comes from the model, no loose plain queries ;D

Comment: Why do people in the PHP world insist on coming up with excuses rather than fixing the problem? It took me literally five seconds to put that escape call in there. **Step 1** in learning how to use MySQL in PHP is proper escaping, it's not optional, it's not "advanced".

Comment: It's not about coming up with excuses, it's about actually **focusing** on the actual problem, giving hints where needed, letting the user to show some research effort. It's about not just spitting out already-chewed code (if possible), but giving guidance. Also, please be considered, the "Why do people in the PHP world ... " can be rather offensive for a lot of people in the PHP world who wouldn't come up with excuses. Generalizing is just rude and I know you know it. If you want to release your frustration do it just on me. And thanks for editing my answer by the way. Relax, and enjoy life!

Comment: I'm only generalizing because the Python, Ruby, Perl, C#, and Java communities here make an effort to promote doing database calls correctly. PHP stands alone in stubborn opposition. If you're writing an answer that uses `mysql_query`, the answer is simply incorrect if you don't escape your data. PHP suffers greatly from w3schools which teaches poisonously bad habits, so it's *especially* important to undo this damage by posting answers that are done properly. The last thing we need is yet another example that's got a giant SQL injection hole in it.

Comment: You are generalizing because you just want to, now you are the one making excuses, I've seen plenty of php answers promoting correct database calls and suggesting people not to `mysql_`. As I also did. I did recommend PDO and also suggested sanitizing the query call. I just didn't write the full code. Thus I understand you, there are plenty of amateur programmers (As I am) in the php community because of the learning curve, but you shouldn't condemn the actual good ones as well.

Comment: What would encourage you to write SQL injection safe answers on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Answering questions specifically targeting safety or SQL injections I mean, sometimes I even just give pseudocode as answers, as long as it's enough to answer the actual question, commenting or addressing possible flaws like in this case. If not, we would have to get into doing everything perfectly, in this case shouldn't we also warn the op about XSS for example, as he is using a form? about using a tinyint or bit field instead of a char/varchar for the 'Y' and 'N' ? about not using inline CSS ?

Comment: XSS is a serious concern as well, but it's not as severe. I just think it's dangerous to give an answer that has an injection bug, as someone just learning PHP will copy-paste it into their application thinking it's the correct way of doing it. Anyway, thanks for your feedback and sorry if I'm coming across as harsh. I'm just trying to  keep the answers here as injection free as possible.

Comment: Don't worry, I understand your harshness, I think our difference is that you think that we should give the exact correct code in the answer, while I think that giving the "guidance" would be enough, and if the OP is interested enough at least he has something to start researching from. I think that If he's just interested on a copy-paste-able working version he would completely miss the point anyway, also I don't like to answer to that kind of users. Both of us has a point anyway, sometimes I do write a very detailed and complete code (When I feel that I'm actually learning from my own answer)